# File In Use - Can not Delete or Replace - ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to replace pictures in my server, User will select a picture from list box then He will select a picture from his PC and then He will click on Replace button to Do the process, Also the uploaded file will resize to old file's dimension. After this Resize the uploaded file should delete and the new image should save on server (overwriting the image which is selected in listbox). Here is the Replace Button's Code Behind:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Save Selected Picture into Server
    string file = Server.MapPath("~/Resources/").ToString() + UploadPic.PostedFile.FileName.ToString();
    UploadPic.PostedFile.SaveAs(file);
    // Resize The Picture in Server
    Bitmap image = new Bitmap(file);
    Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value);
    image = ResizeImage(image, picture.Width, picture.Height);
    // Saving the New Picture in Server
    File.Delete(file);
    image.Save("~/Resources/" + Path.GetFileName(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value));
}
```

But It seems Both uploaded file and the image which is selected from listbox is in use, I tried disposing so many things such as ListBox,UploadControl,picture etc. But did not find a working solution.
File.Delete will gives the "File in use" Error
image.save will gives the "GDI+ interface" Error which means another file with the same name is in use.

Any Help is really Appreciated

Comment: You need to dispose of those bitmaps, I think that is the source of your problem. If you add `using` statements does it still happen?

Comment: Well, you still need them, you have a memory leek if you don't. Also, edit your question and show how you did it. Also include the code for ResizeImage the thing locking the file might be there

Comment: I have found the problem. It was somewhere inside listbox selectedchanged event. But Now There is another problem, after replacing image I can see it in windows explorer and visual studio solution (the new image), but running the web form again will show the old file image which does not exists anymore and it is so strange!!! Where is the problem?

Comment: I found it, I should clear browser's cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of saving the uploaded file somewhere before working on it you should be able to create your [`Bitmap`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx) directly from it using [`UploadPic.PostedFile.InputStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba4sack9(v=vs.110).aspx). You can then eliminate your `File.Delete()` call, too. I don't have an IDE in front of my but this should roughly work:

```
//Create an image from the posted file's stream
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(UploadPic.PostedFile.InputStream);
Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value);
image = ResizeImage(image, picture.Width, picture.Height);
image.Save("~/Resources/" + Path.GetFileName(ListBox1.SelectedItem.Value));
```

Comment: Good Chris, But still there is problem with saving image. It is using with some part of the page and I do not know where it is!